# Css hover work, but not(:hover) don't do its purpose

Tags: html, css

I would like my hover to make the "hidding" div appear by fading in and then appearing, and when not(:hover) I want it to fade out and then disappear, I've tried this:

```css
.éléments:not(:hover) #hidding {
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s, font-size 2s 1s;
}

.éléments:hover #hidding {
  background-color: #97e6bc;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: font-size 1s, opacity 2s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="éléments">
  <div class="école">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
  <div class="école">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
  <div class="école">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But for an unknown reason the div instantly disappears and only the text seems affected by the `:not(:hover)`, can someone explain me what is happening please?

Comment: You **cannot have more than *one*** `<div id="hidding">`. `id` **must be unique at all times**. Use `<div class="hidding">` instead. https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp

Comment: to start with you need to avoid using characater like `é` with anything, you will get errors and you will never know why

Comment: you didn't define the font-size on the hover state

Comment: thanks for yours comments I learned a lot of things, so now i have this : https://jsfiddle.net/g4pt3qh1/1/ but it still don't work
ps: wow who downvotes a question ?

Comment: Do you really really need to animate the `transition` property, like in your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code, as noticed by many others:

- Firstly, as connexo said, `id`s must be **unique**. Use `class` instead.
- Secondly, as  Temani Afif said, you shouldn't use special charactors like `é`. It's a bad coding practice that may cause errors.
- The `.elements:not(:hover)` isn't a good idea for many reasons.
- Don't put inanimate properties, like `background-color`, into a `:hover` Pseudo class.
- You're trying to animate the `transition` property. This might be the source of most of your glitches.

But importantly, the use of `.elements:not(:hover)` is nonexistent. It seemes what you are trying to achieve is just `.elements` itself. The `:not(:hover)` is implied I guess. You should put all your default css formatting in `.elements` itself, including all your transitions. Put only properties you want to animate on `:hover` in the hover Pseudo class.
[W3Schools: CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```css
.elements .hidding {
  height: 0;
  width: 15em;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #97e6bc;
  transition: opacity 1s, height 1s ease-out, width 1s ease-out;
}

.elements .hidding>p {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

.elements:hover>.ecole>.hidding {
  width: 20em;
  height: 3em;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
    <div class="hidding">
      <p>hidding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
    <div class="hidding">
      <p>hidding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
    <div class="hidding">
      <p>hidding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wouldn't animate the `transition` property, (I don't even think it's remotely possible). You might have better luck with [CSS animations.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot have more than *one*** `<div id="hidding">`. `id` **must be unique at all times**. Use `<div class="hidding">` instead.

> https://www.w3schools.com/hTML/html_id.asp

That being said, it is bad practice to use non-ascii characters in development.

I corrected these issues.

The cause of your problem is that you have some properties which a) are only defined in `:hover` state (`width`, `padding`, `margin`) and b) which are not defined when it comes to your rules for `transition`.

The second issue is that your `.element:not(:hover) .hidding` really should simply just be `.elements .hidding`. The reason for this is that anything that is defined in `.element:not(:hover) .hidding` immediately is no longer applied at all when hovering `.elements`.

```css
.elements .hidding {
  background-color: #97e6bc;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 20em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.elements:hover .hidding {
  background-color: #97e6bc;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ecole">
    <h3>Where is Charly ?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="hidding">
    <p>hidding</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh okey, so my error was to not define some properties in the hover and  the class properties, but now I am testing to have like, just the opacity to be animated, and again, it fade in but doesn't fade out whereas opacity is defined in both hover and the class 
https://jsfiddle.net/4jetLw6u/5/
it seems that it doesn't make the "transition" in ".elements .hidding "

Answer (score 0):

It works but you have written `opacity 2s 1s;`. This means opacity starts to be 1 after 1 seconds in 2 seconds of transition.
This is not the correct way. Use `.elements #hidding{` instead. Then `.elements:hover #hidding{`. This question if full of wrongs :). Try to learn better before asking [jsfiddle.net/90v2yLq8](http://jsfiddle.net/90v2yLq8)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/srd2zkaj/5/ like this ? I tried it but it doesn't work too

Comment: I didn't understood this part : ""you have written opacity 2s 1s;. This means opacity starts to be 1 after 2 seconds.""
for me It should mean that the transition will start 1s late, and will take 2s